# Always on top Popup windows

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog, popupwindow, always-on-top

I need to have a popup window that will overlay a current window such that the user can click back and forth without the popup disappearing behind it. The popup must also be movable.  I've tried a few pseudo popups like Zebra. They have a good modal popup,  but their displays are not movable and are limited to the current screen only.

Imagine: The user is reading a record and wants to popup more information. Then the user wants to change records on the main screen and bring up a second popup so the two popups display at the same time - and so forth. The user may want to go to another main screen and popup more for further consideration such that there could be multiple popups independent of any main screen and always on top (not of each other, I realize).

In case it matters, I'm on Windows 7 using JQuery along with PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Check out bootstrap CSS's modal dialog.

Comment: Sounds like you want something more like an MDI.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are going to want to use the JQuery Dialog Box (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default) to create your "popup". With JQuery you'll be able to crete as many "popup" windows as you want.

The difficulty will be "changing the main window" which you would have to load in instead of switching pages in order to keep all your popups. Otherwise you would need to store what popups exist, with all their information in order to re-load them when you switch main windows.

And of course, your popups if you do them through JQuery Dialog Box will always be limited to the Browser window.

Comment: The $.Dialog boxes I've tried work well enough, but  don't move, and  are tied to current browser . I've researched enough to be convinced this is too difficult a task. I'll pose a different approach question on another thread. One that involves keeping track of window IDs and focus(). Thanks.